# Minimum character count on body field in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, word-count, charactercount

I am having a very hard time getting a body field to have a minimum character count of 2000 incl. spaces. If the field has less than 2000 charaters, it should not be possible to save the node.

So far i have:

```
<?php

function esund_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    // Normally a switch is used because you may want to alter more than
    // one form and it is easy to add a new case for each form.
    if ($form_id == 'forslag_node_form') {
        $form['body_field']['body']['#description'] = "Description of the content of the post, which should also indicate what the motivation is to hold the post, and what problem or question topic highlights? The description must min. fill 2,000 characters incl. spaces and max. 4000.";
    }
}

function esund_menu_alter(&$items) {
    unset($items['node']);
}
```

I found the following using a google search on the topic, however i have no idea how to integrate the following code into the above and make a minimum charater count:

```
<?php
function minimum_words_text_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form['#parameters'][0] == 'node_type_form') {
                $form['submission']['min_word_count']['#type'] = 'textfield';
                unset($form['submission']['min_word_count']['#options']);
        }
}
?>
```

I am using Drupal 6.31

Cheers

Comment: Drupal 6 has a minimum word count feature built in. Go to the node type edit form and you'll see a select list.  The last snippet you posted seems to be from a different module.

Comment: Hi Ayesh,

I am not looking for a minimum word count, but at minimum charater count. Also, these are pre-defined values, i need to specify my own value.

Answer (score 0):

Using following 2 hooks you can achieve this.

1. [HOOK_FORM_ALTER](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6)
2. [HOOK_VALIDATE](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!node.php/function/hook_validate/6)

In `form_alter` add custom validation, then under `hook_validate` you can set min character limit validation.